# Magento site not working since being moved

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I developed a magento site locally and it was and still is working fine. I need to put it on a public URL to show people though so I've set it up on a subdomain.

I have uploaded all of the files, copied the database to the live server, amended the database connection details and cleared the cache and session folders. I just get a load of wierd symbols when I try and view it in my browser. It is at ***[Click me](http://mw.rnmcloud.com/)***

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the settings of the webservers are alike. If it is a cloud spaced hoster ask them if their server is capable of running Magento.

Also make sure the compiler is disabled and there are no other cache modules active.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "copy" a Magento database, you'll have to create a new one at your new location.

Every installation needs its own database as many variables are different...

Answer (score 0):

Copy it over and amend the `core_config_data` table so it contains the new URLs of your store.  You will also want to flush the cache and empty out any session data in the database, as it will relate to your old URLs (probably won't matter too much, though).